# Why doesn't the Last Saved date update when saving in Microsoft Word?

Tags: microsoft-word

I want to add an automatically updating "Last Updated" date to a document in Microsoft Word.

Following the instructions from [Microsoft Support](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Insert-the-date-and-time-a-document-was-created-last-printed-or-last-saved-A2C4E3CC-B096-4C50-9395-5DCA9F3BEED1), I add the date to my footer. (**Insert → Quick Parts → Field → Date and Time → SaveDate**)

[image: Last Saved Date]

I was disappointed to learn that the Save Date didn't update automatically when I saved my document. I needed to manually update the field by:

- Saving the document.
- Right-clicking the Date field and selecting *Update Field*.
- Saving the document a second time.

Normally, Microsoft Word has an "Update automatically" option when adding the time or date to a document. Unfortunately, this feature is only displayed when adding the [***current***](https://wordribbon.tips.net/T010078_Inserting_Todays_Date.html) date to a document. The option is not shown when adding a Date Field, such as "SaveDate".

**Why doesn't the Last Saved date update automatically when saving my document in Microsoft Word?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Turns out the date field ***does*** update automatically, but only after closing and re-opening the document.

> **Note: The date may not update in your document unless you close, then
> re-open the file** or right-click the field and select “Update Field“.
>
> Now the date in your document will be inserted into the document and
> will update automatically based on the selection you made whenever you
> open the [Word] document.
>
> <sub>[Technipages - Word 2016 & 2013: Insert Date that Updates Itself Automatically](https://www.technipages.com/word-insert-date-that-updates-itself-automatically)</sub>

Comment: I can't decide whether to vote this answer up or down. It's nice to have an answer, but the answer is so incredibly disappointing... What's the point in having a special SaveDate field if it doesn't actually represent the date the document was saved? If I were alert enough to remember to close and reopen the document every time I intentionally saved, I could update the date myself.

Comment: @Sigfried Agreed, it is disappointing. I've updated my wording to avoid implying this is an ideal solution.